How to make centerdot work with just one argument
I am trying to use centerdot instead of noncommutative multiply for some bosonic algebra and I cannot figure out how to get CenterDot[a] to simplify to a. I tried CenterDot[x_]:=x but this gives a recursion limit error.

You should have mentioned that you've set Flat attribute on CenterDot, and you should have read the linked answer to your previous question more carefully. (-1)

thank you and sorry
